# Why is installing the latest Linux kernel for Ubuntu taking so long?

Tags: kernel, dpkg, update-manager, cinnamon

I ran the software updater, which updated Ubuntu base on 32 bit 15.04, which as I understand it includes the Linux kernel and it was taking so long (after several hours it still hadn't finished) I felt it must have already finished the job, just the GUI must have stalled. So what I did was I rebooted my PC as I thought this would get the new kernel up and running. But when I tried to install subversion once rebooted it gave me the error:

```
    E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but it is taking forever (four hours so far) to finish the job. I have 3.8 GB RAM, my CPU is an Intel Core i5 M460 @ 2.53 GHz x 2, I have over 260 GB HDD space free and my current kernel is 3.19.0-20-generic, but the version of the kernel I am attempting to install with dpkg is 3.19.0-21-generic. If relevant my desktop environment is Cinnamon 2.2.16, although I am running Ubuntu and not Linux Mint. This is my output message from running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`:

```
Setting up linux-image-3.19.0-21-generic (3.19.0-21.21) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-21-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-21-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-21-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.19.0-21-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-21-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-21-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-21-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.19.0-21-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-21-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-21-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-21-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.19.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-21-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 3.19.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-21-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.19.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-21-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-21-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-21-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-20-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-15-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
```

Comment: It can't take hours unless it is downloaded slowly.

Comment: My internet connection is fine, web pages load without a problem, downloading with wget (which I started long after I ran this command if you're wondering whether this could be what's slowing it) is working fine with >200 kB/s achieved easily, and up to 700 kB/s possible.

Comment: Id try to purge old unused kernels first. maybe you have too many kernel modules that are taking a long time to compile? just a thought

Comment: @Zeus77 I think I only have the one, namely the one I'm using as running `uname -r` gives: `3.19.0-20-generic`.

Comment: Nope, there are 3.19.0-21-generic, 3.19.0-20-generic and 3.19.0-15-generic, according to the above output.

Comment: OK, how do I remove the others then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, I found the solution myself! What I did was I rebooted from a live USB and repaired grub (according to [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/93125)), as I noticed that line in the message generated by `sudo dpkg --configure -a` namely `Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.` and it made me wonder what would happen if I repaired grub. After booting back into Ubuntu on my HDD I re-ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and it installed the new kernel in what seemed like less than a minute.